# VS402872: Duplicate release pipeline stages " " found. Specify a different name and try again

Tags: azure, devops, pipeline, release, cicd

I was making some changes to the Release Pipelines, in which we divided 1 pipeline (Dev, PreProd, and Prod) into three separate release pipelines. After the change, we lost the Release history in all pipelines.

Now I am trying to "Revert pipeline" by going to history. It appears, Azure DevOps is confused with two different stages as one. Thus, when I try to save it, below error appears.

[image]

Release pipeline does not support YAML editing, so I am unsure if this is a bug in Azure DevOps, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing in-depth research and consulting with my colleagues. I have found the Release history cannot be recovered after we change the name of the Release pipeline.

Thus, we have decided to move ahead with the lost history and be more careful in the future.